# Teamcity REST API: How to get agent of last successful build

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Is there a way in Teamcity REST API to get the agent name of the last successful build. I am using Teamcity 8.0.6. I tried this

```
http://<TeamcityServer>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:BuildId/builds?status=SUCCESS
```

But the result returned doesn't contain Agent name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will give you the last successful build details for a given build type (where BUILDTYPE is the btxxx id):

`http://<TeamcityServer>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/buildType:(id:BUILDTYPE),status:SUCCESS`

The response contains the agent details in the `/build/agent` element.

Comment: Slightly modified, it to get just the agent name.
http://<TeamcityServer>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/buildType:(id:BuildId),status:SUCCESS/resulting-properties/system.agent.name

Comment: Just for good measure, on command line using curl and xmlstarlet: `curl -g "http://<TeamcityServer>/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/buildType:(id:BUILDTYPE),status:SUCCESS" -s | xml sel -t -m "/build/agent" -v "@name"`